# Color subitem's specific text

Tags: vb.net, listview

I Want to check subitems' text property with string var property and if those do not matches, highlight the non-matching text in `listview1.subitem`

```
  If founditem.SubItems(2).Text <> data then
   'highlight not equal text in lv1.subitem with yellow
  End if
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

add a listview to your project and try this one

```
ListView1.Columns.Add("col1")
    ListView1.Columns.Add("col2")
    ListView1.Columns.Add("col3")
    ListView1.Columns.Add("col4")
    ListView1.Columns.Add("col5")
    Dim itms() As String = {"55", "55", "55", "55", "55"}
    For x As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itms(x))
        lvi.SubItems.Add(itms(x) & "-1")
        lvi.SubItems.Add(itms(x) & "-2")
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    Next
    itms = {"55", "55", "55", "55", "AA"}
    For x As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itms(x))
        lvi.SubItems.Add(itms(x) & "-1")
        lvi.SubItems.Add(itms(x) & "-2")
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
    Next


    Dim control_str() As String = {"55", "55", "55", "55", "AA"}
    For Each itm As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        For i As Integer = 0 To itm.SubItems.Count - 1
            If itm.SubItems(i).Text <> control_str(i) Then
                itm.SubItems(i).BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next


    Next
```

Comment: Its close, but it doesnt c light up specific text, fo exmaple 55 55 55 55 55 - already in listbox  in third column(subitems(2)) and  data as string contains 55 55 55 55 AA, so what i want its highlight only last 55, becaouse only this is diffrent

Comment: With a standard `ListView` and `ListViewItem` you cannot have multiple fonts/colours in a single item.

Comment: okay,therefore what im doing worng here, it doesnt light up, Despite the fact that the conditions are true.  If founditem.SubItems(2).Text <> data Then
                            founditem.SubItems(2).BackColor = Color.Red
                            founditem.SubItems(2).Text = data
                        End If